# MacOS dmg file question

Tags: macos, dmg, zip

Not entirely sure if this is where to ask this, but I can't find another place to...

I've recently switched from Windows to Mac and I am trying to understand more in depth what I'm working with.

My question is: are `.dmg` files the equivalent of `.zip` files in Windows? I came to this theory when downloading a `.dmg` and when I opened it, it contained a `.app` and and text file `read me`. To me, this seems like a compressed file.

Is this correct?

Comment: For Analogical purposes - a `.dmg` is much more similar to a `.iso` file than a `.zip` file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [DMG file (Apple Disk Image)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image) is a disk image file that is mounted as a volume, just like a physical disk. They can be password protected and compressed (like ZIPs), and are usually used for packaging and downloading Mac software (amongst other things).

DMGs are exclusively an Apple file format (though can be opened as read-only on Windows computers with 3rd party software), while a ZIP file is universal, and can be opened on both Mac and Windows. The nice thing about them is the ability to mount them, as I mentioned earlier. When you open a ZIP, it extracts the files to your computer, taking up more space on your hard drive. A DMG once mounted, however, can be interacted with and ejected without copying any files or taking up space on your hard drive.

[@klanomath](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/93229/klanomath) said it best in their comment on this answer, so I will quote them here:

> All valid DMGs contain a file system - so they are mounted exactly like a real partition to a file system. They get their own device/disk identifier (like all disks) Check `diskutil list` after opening a DMG.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! I do have another question though. I pulled an application from a downloaded DMG file and upon doing this, what appears to be an icon of a disk harddrive, ex: [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjS1brcnLDOAhWD5oMKHRGQC-0QjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fosxdaily.com%2F2014%2F06%2F09%2Finstall-os-x-yosemite-on-external-drive%2F&bvm=bv.129391328,d.amc&psig=AFQjCNHyOVNozkI-vPkPu6d0BHPamEwVeg&ust=1470690897952058) and I'm not quite sure I understand how this works, could you please explain?

Comment: @Nick that is the "mounting" I mentioned; it is basically mounted as a volume in Finder.

Comment: I would love to improve or clarify my answer for the down voter?

Comment: @ruddfawcett I didn't downvote your question. A dmg is not necessarily compressed. The "**almost** "mounted"" is also debatable. All valid dmgs contain a file system - so they are mounted exactly like a real partition to a file system. They get their own device/disk identifier (like all disks) Check `diskutil list` after opening a dmg.

Comment: I down voted originally but the edit has removed the errors - .dmg s are disk systems and only incidentally act like zip - i.e. tne opposite of your original last sentence

Comment: @klanomath thanks -- I clearly didn't know as much as I thought I did. I have clarified my answer above, quoting your comment.

Comment: @Mark thanks -- I tried to fix that in the last edit. As I mentioned to klanomath above, my familiarity with DMGs clearly wasn't what I thought it was.

Comment: You might want to reword "_DMGs are exclusively a Mac file format (a ZIP file is universal, and can be opened on both Mac and Windows)_" as .dmg files can be accessed under Windows with the right software, albeit read-only. I'd also say it was an Apple file format.

Comment: @user3439894 thanks! I've clarified that above.

Comment: One thing not mentioned so far - after opening the .dmg by double-clicking [its window should usually automatically open in Finder as well as showing as a mounted disk to the filesystem], unless there is a 'double-click-me' type installer inside [relatively rare], then the usual method to install is simply to drag the app to your Applications folder [this will copy the app, not make an alias/shortcut]. Some .dmgs have an Applications folder icon inside them, which is actually a link to *your own* Apps folder, making the whole process simpler. [cont'd...]

Comment: [...cont'd] Once copied, right click inside the open .dmg window & Eject it.

Answer (score 0):

The .dmg file can be seen as a parallel to the .iso image file (only in a smaller size). 
You can mount this kind of image file:

- (Windows) in a virtual drive and access it from there
- (OSX) in /Volumes

Comment: DMG files aren't always smaller than ISO files, and to the best of my knowledge they can't be mounted in virtual drives on Windows (although I may be wrong.)

Comment: I meant to say that this kind of image files can be mounted, .iso in Windows and .dmg in OSX.